# Why aren't any texture on .obj-s? (Three.js)

Tags: three.js

I am working on an anatomy application based on three.js. Recently I am trying to visualize a skeleton and an ecorche model. Both of us are .obj-s with an .mtl file and there are jpeg files as textures. My problem is that my app visualize the two models but on the ecorche the are no textures and the skeleton is black. The problem is somewhere in the obj and mtl loader. I guess there is also an easier way to load the models.

The files of a model is in a separate folder.

My other question is how I can manage to make a button that change the actual model to the other one.

Thank you for your help!

Here is the code:

```
if (!Detector.webgl) {
        Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
    }
    var container;
    var camera, controls, scene, renderer;
    var lighting, ambient, keyLight, fillLight, backLight;
    var windowDivideX = window.innerWidth / 3.4;
    var files=['WorkAlpha.obj','untitled.mtl'];

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {
        container = document.createElement('viewer');
        document.body.appendChild(container);

        /*Creating Camera*/
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, windowDivideX / 
        window.innerHeight, 1, 100);
        camera.position.y = 0;
        camera.position.z = 40;
        camera.position.x = 0;

        /* Scene and Lights */
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        lighting = false;
        ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xEAE1EA, 0.3);
        scene.add(ambient);
        keyLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xEAE1EA, 0.6);

        //(new THREE.Color('hsl(30, 80%, 0%)'), 1.0);
        keyLight.position.set(-100, 0, 100);
        fillLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xEAE1EA, 0.6);


        //(new THREE.Color('hsl(30, 80%, 0%)'), 0.6);
        fillLight.position.set(100, 0, 100);
        backLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.6);
        backLight.position.set(100, 0, -100).normalize();


        //ambient.intensity = 0.1;
        scene.add(keyLight);
        scene.add(fillLight);
        scene.add(backLight);


        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        /* Model */

        var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader.setBaseUrl('assets/');
        mtlLoader.setPath('assets/');
        mtlLoader.load(files [0],  function (materials) {
            materials.preload();
            var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
            objLoader.setPath('assets/');
            objLoader.load('WorkAlpha.obj', function (object) {

            object.position.y = 3;object.position.x = 0;
            object.position.z = 0;
            object.name = "muscles";
            scene.add(object);
            });
        });


        mtlLoader.setBaseUrl('skeleton/');
        mtlLoader.setPath('skeleton/');
        mtlLoader.load(files[1],  function (materials) {
            materials.preload();
            var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
            objLoader.setPath('skeleton/');
            objLoader.load('untitled.obj', function (object) {

                object.position.y = -15;object.position.x = 0;
                object.position.z = 0;
                object.name = "skeleton";
                scene.add(object);
            });
        });

        /* Renderer */
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);


        renderer.setSize(windowDivideX, window.innerHeight);


        renderer.setClearColor(0xC9D2D3);
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        /* Controls */
        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, 
        renderer.domElement);
        controls.enableDamping = true;
        controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
        controls.enableZoom = true;
        controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI/2;

        /* Events */
        window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyboardEvent, false);
    }

    function onWindowResize() {
        camera.aspect = windowDivideX / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize(windowDivideX, window.innerHeight);
        }

    function onKeyboardEvent(e) {
        if (e.code === 'KeyL') {
            lighting = !lighting;
            if (lighting) {
                ambient.intensity = 0.25;
                scene.add(keyLight);
                scene.add(fillLight);
                scene.add(backLight);
            } else {
                ambient.intensity = 1.0;
                scene.remove(keyLight);
                scene.remove(fillLight);
                scene.remove(backLight);
            }
        }
    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        controls.update();
        render();
    }

    function render() {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
```

Here you can see the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title></title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <script src="three.js"></script>
    <script src="Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="MTLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="TrackballControls.js"></script>
    <script 
    src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/Projector.js">
    </script>
    <script 
   src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/renderers/CanvasRenderer.js">
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">

</head>
<body>
    <script src="3d.js"></script>      
</body>
</html>
```